# Yii Condition with multiple AND/ORs - Operator Precedence

Tags: php, mysql, yii

What needs to be modified here to get a working select statement?

**UPDATED** in regards to Jon's response.

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'GroupId', GxHtml::listDataEx(Group::model()
               ->findAll(array(
                    'condition'=>'SC=:stat AND Pri=:pri AND Type=:typ OR Type=:typ2 OR Type=:typ3', 
                    'params'=>array(':stat'=>'A', ':pri'=>'Y', ':typ'=>'A', ':typ2'=>'B', ':typ3'=>'C')),
                    'GroupId', 'Name')); 
?>
```

Which yeilds:

```
system.db.CDbCommand.query
    (SELECT * FROM `group` `t` 
    WHERE SC=:stat AND Pri=:pri AND Type!=:typ 
    OR Type!=:typ2 OR Type!=:typ3. 
    Bound with :stat='A', :pri='Y', :typ='A', :typ2='B', :typ3='C')
```

The problem here is not everything is taken into account.  Can I add Operator Precedence into the Yii code somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply use the parenthesis to have the operator precedence you need.

Comment: I have tried added () or {} to no avail...results never changed.  Could be as a result of me not including them as needed though.

Comment: @enfield You have to use the (...). If using them the result doesn't fit your needs, maybe you're not running the right sql statement. Try to run it using phpmyadmin (or something like it) and see if the result you get is what you expected.

Comment: Thanks I have been playing around with direct SQL also before posting this question.  Using { } I can include multiple ORs just fine.  When it comes to writing the Yii equivalent the best I have been able to achieve is multiple ANDs as soon as I include multiple ORs with it the desired result is not achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably got the operator usage wrong.

Consider that if `typ == 'A'` and `typ2 == 'B'`, then

```
type != 'A' OR type != 'B'
```

will be `true` no matter what `type` is. You may have wanted this instead:

```
'condition'=>'SC=:stat AND Pri=:pri AND Type!=:typ AND Type!=:typ2 AND Type!=:typ3',
```

Other than that, you can simply add parens to fix the precedence if it's a problem.

Comment: Great point!  Yes this hold true for what I posted.  In another attempt I listed out all the variables using equals rather than not equals and still everything does not work.  I will update this question removing the not equals